# Bash: splitting filename by space? A backup rollback script

Tags: bash

I need some help with Bash. I am a Python/Rust guy and do not understand bash too well. I have a "backup" script which copies a selected file to a "$filename $datetime.backup" file. Now I need to write a rollback script which copies latest backup file over the original (without space and datetime and backup suffix). Any guides will be appreciated.

Backup script, for your convenience:

```
set -e

DT=$(date --iso=seconds)

for f in $*
do
    OLD="${f%/}"
    NEW="${f%/} $DT.backup"
    cp --no-clobber --recursive "$OLD" "$NEW"
done
```

Comment: (`for f in $*` will break when an argument contains funny stuff. Just `for f` would suffice.)

Comment: Thanks. I had issues when backedup files contained spaces or / (a directory name, pressed tab).

Comment: @ArekBulski : Why then don't your write the whole stuff in Python or Rust? I have no experience with Rust, but at least in Python you have everything you need to do the task. If you write this with the goal to become proficient in bash, you should write that part of the Rollback script you already have, so that we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion to get the original name back.

```sh
for b in *.backup ; do
    original=${b% *}
    cp "$b" "$original"
done
```

`${b% *}` removes everything after the last space from $b.

Comment: Actually the rollback script is supposed to take the original filename. The problem is, given so many backups, which one to take? Some sort of sorting and tail would be needed? Ahh your script goes over backups in sorted order, yes? So last cp wins.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Yay!

```
set -e

LB=$(ls $1 *.backup | sort --reverse | head -n 1)
echo "Moving $1 to trash for safe keeping"
trash "$1"
echo "Copying from $LB"
cp --no-clobber --recursive "$LB" "$1"
```